# gvim long multiline string highlighting

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I make extensive use of multiline docstrings in my python source code to include doctests.  Unfortunately, vim/gvim seems to have a hard time with syntax highlighting, occasionally losing it's place and forgetting that it's in the middle of a string literal, and the highlighting "flips" from string to source and source to string.

I can scroll up to the top and back down again, and vim *usually* fixes the problem, but sometimes it takes a few tries.

Aside from making my docstrings shorter, Is there a way to help vim keep the highlighting on these long literals in order?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`:syntax syn` controls how Vim synchronizes the syntax state that should apply at a particular point in the text (`:help syn-sync`). For the most accurate sync (but this will slow vim down), try:

```
autocmd BufEnter * :syntax sync fromstart
```

Or if you want to sync manually whenever you notice it's wrong, try this command (you could map it to a keyboard shortcut):

```
:syntax sync fromstart
```

You might also find `minlines` useful. From `:help syn-sync`

> If the "minlines={N}" argument is given, the parsing always starts at least
>   that many lines backwards.  This can be used if the parsing may take a few
>   lines before it's correct, or when it's not possible to use syncing.

So putting this in your .vimrc might help you:

```
syntax sync minlines=500
```

Edit: found this page which has everything you need:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_syntax_highlighting

Comment: I use `syn sync fromstart` regularly (but not quite always) and haven't ever really noticed any slowdown, even when editing several hundred kilobyte JavaScript files. Modern hardware's pretty powerful. With HTML I find it especially useful.

Comment: True. Just as a reference, on a core i7 with 8gig of RAM and a fast hard drive, the point at which a slowdown is perceptible is if I go beyond about 60k normal-length lines (file size of about 2.5MB).

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want sync fromstart for *all* types of code you are editing, just html. If that's the case, add this to your vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType html autocmd BufEnter * :syntax sync fromstart
```